# How can I detect and remount my time machine sparsebundle?

Tags: network, script, automount

I currently have my Time Machine sparse bundle residing on a network drive plugged in to my router. I have a script that runs at login that auto connects to the shared drive and mounts the sparsebundle image as a device for backups. Here's what it looks like:

```
try
   mount volume "smb://readyshare/MacBackup"
end try

do shell script "hdiutil attach -mountpoint /Volumes/MacBackup/ /Volumes/MacBackup/TimeMachine.sparsebundle"
```

However, I've noticed that from time the time the device will automatically disconnect itself. Usually this happens when I leave for lunch and the MacBook Pro goes to sleep after a while.

Often I don't notice this until I get an error message about my backup device not being able to perform the backup.

Is there a way I can modify this script (or create a new one) that can detect when my sparsebundle device has been ejected and remount it?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can point Time Machine directly at a network share and it should handle this for you automatically. Maybe your question relates to an older version of macOS.